# What happens when a nonce is reused (WPA2)

Tags: nonce

I am trying to understand the KRACK on WPA2. But in [their paper](https://papers.mathyvanhoef.com/ccs2017.pdf) (PDF) it just simply states that

> By forcing nonce reuse in this manner, the encryption protocol can be attacked.

But I cannot find an explanation WHY this is possible. I.e. what exactly happens, that when a nonce is reused, the encryption protocol can be attacked?

Comment: TL;DR: (anybody who wants to, please write a proper answer), WPA2 uses CTR mode for bulk encryption and with a fixed nonce you learn message XORs.